# How to use currying to write a tail recursive function for summing factorials given a certain bound

Tags: function-construction, recursion, functional-style

I am very confused about how can i use currying to write a tail recursive function for summing factorials within a certain bound or summing the bounds i.e. given [1,5] i should be getting 1!+2!+3!+4!+5! and for summing bounds 1+2+3+4+5. How can i construct two elegant functions using currying.

My code currently looks like this:

```
factorial[n_] := (loopfact[n, acc_] := If[n == 0, acc, loopfact[n - 1, acc*n]];
Return@loopfact[n, 1]);

sum[a_, b_, acc_] := Block[{x, ac}, x = a; ac = acc;
loop[x_, ac_] := If[x > b, ac, loop[x + 1, ac + factorial[x]]];
loop[x, ac]]

sum[0, 5, 0] (* using the function above *)
(* 154 *)

sum[a_, b_, acc_] := Module[{x, ac}, x = a; ac = acc;
loop[x_, ac_] := If[x > b, ac, loop[x + 1, ac + # &@x]];
loop[x, ac]]

sum[0, 50, 0] (* using the second function definition *)
(* 1275 *)
```

Also could someone kindly explain to me how currying works in Mathematica. Thanks !

Comment: Is there a reason why you can't use `Plus @@ Factorial /@ Range[1, 5]`?

Comment: I am aware of that. just for the purpose of knowing how to morph my code from higher order functions to employing currying. Also, because i wish to understand how currying works in mathematica

Answer (score 5):

If you are more interested in currying than tail-recursion, this is not the answer you want. However, I don't think currying, and certainly not your approach to currying, is very suited to *Mathematica*. (It will be interesting if Leonid Shifrin or someone else of his level of expertise will step in a show that I'm wrong).

If tail-recursive is really the focus of your question, then I recommend a Scheme style approach with tail-recursive helper functions. This is very clean stylistically (no `If`, but only pattern matching on arguments).

First the factorial.

```
g[1, val_] = val;
g[k_ /; k > 1, val_] := g[k - 1, k val]
f[1] = 1;
f[k_Integer /; k > 1] := g[k - 1, k]
```

Now the summation.

```
s[a_, a_, val_] := val + f[a]
s[a_, b_, val_] := s[a, b - 1, val + f[b]]
sum[a_Integer /; a > 0, b_Integer] /; b >= a := s[a, b, 0]

sum[1, 5] == Plus @@ Factorial /@ Range[1, 5]
```

> `True`

Edge case.

```
sum[10, 10] == Factorial[10]
```

> `True`